# Where to mount shared data fs?

Tags: linux, mount, share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mounting location of non-standard file systems](https://serverfault.com/questions/153348/mounting-location-of-non-standard-file-systems)

This is more a 'poll' type question then problem solving one...

I got a big file system that is use by many thru ssh and samba to share videos, pictures and exchange other documents. I usualy mount this at /home/share, but it dont feel it is right anymore. I am looking for a better suited mount point. I will be upgrading the hd very soon but i still dont know where to mount it. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate...

Where do you mount your shared file system?
Where is the traditional mount point for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

/net/hostname/export via autofs.  Auto configured, self documenting.

Answer (score 0):

These days that kind of thing is usually kept under /srv somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reference to consult is the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/). You can consult it for guidance and suggestions, in particular regarding `/srv` which is open to structuring according to your needs.

Comment: The FHS doc specify that /var/www is for proxy and cache. Should web sites be placed on /srv/www/ insted of /var/www/ like Debian's default suggest?

Comment: @John: Not all systems comply with FHS. `/var` should generally be used for runtime data, but it's not at all uncommon for web sites to be located there or in `/home`, etc.