# How do I know what the standard location is for putting server files on Linux systems?

Tags: linux, files

I'm just getting into doing my own hosting, and it seems like there are often common practices for choosing file locations.

For example, I found [this website](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/ssl-directory) that says that there are standard places for storing SSL certificates that vary based on distro:

> Linux has its designated directories for everything. You’re already familiar with the /var, /etc and other directories which are part of the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS).
>
> Well, guess what, there is a designated location for storing SSL certificates too.
>
> Ubuntu:
> `/etc/ssl/certs/`
>
> CentOS:
> `/etc/pki/tls/certs/`

Are these locations documented anywhere more formally? I'm imagining something like "Ubuntu standard file locations for common critical files".

I read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/153348/mounting-location-of-non-standard-file-systems), and it seems like there sometimes isn't a standard. But this article seems to say otherwise, at least when it comes to certain files.

Perhaps related is the different ways an nginx config folder can be laid out (with config files saved in `conf.d` on some distros and in `sites-available` on other distros. Where on earth do these differences come from? As far as I know, nginx is a single application published by a single organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no authority on where exactly files should go. Read any documentation: how to guides, reference manuals, and review anything a package installs that looks like a configuration file.

Someone set out to build https enabled nginx a long time ago, and their packaging decisions were repeated in lots of documentation. Repeat for every package on the system, which builds up a set of conventions for where things are.

Realize that even the same source code can be heavily modified and still function. Config files, added on supporting scripts,  code patches that are not upstream, compile time options. Not ideal, but these differences do exist.

Both Red Hat/CentOS and Debian/Ubuntu ship a ca-certificates package based on Mozilla's work, as a big bundle. But as well as the system PKI directory being different, the tools to update the bundle are as well. Debian has [update-ca-certificates](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ca-certificates/update-ca-certificates.8.en.html) which is openssl based, while EL has [update-ca-trust](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-shared-system-certificates) which abstracts this into a p11-kit library with a `trust` binary.

PKI is quite a general problem, so know that putting certs other places is common and can be acceptable. There is no reason why a web server's certificate needs to be in the system store. [Debian handbook's httpd recipe](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.http-web-server.en.html#sect.apache-ssl) shows just that: might as well use Let's Encrypt certs if available, and those by default are at `/etc/letsencrypt/`.